# Unable to Compile Parse + Facebook SDK (Apple Mach-O Linker Error)

Tags: ios, facebook, parse-platform, linker-errors

I am trying to use add Facebook SDK to my iOS Parse Project. I am trying to

I followed the setup instruction [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started):

In my bridging header I added:

```
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
#import <FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit.h>
#import <ParseFacebookUtilsV4/PFFacebookUtils.h>
```

**Up to this point everything compiles fine**, but when I try to add a loginToFacebook code, I get a **Apple Mach-o Linker Error**

```
   var permissionArray = ["user_about_me","user_relationships","user_relationships","user_location"];

    PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions(permissionArray) { (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if (user == nil) {
            println("Canceled the Facebook login.");
        } else if (user!.isNew) {
            println("User signed up and logged in through Facebook!");
        } else {
            println("login through Facebook");
        }
    }
```

[image: Error Screenshot]

Any Idea what have I done wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I have done parse+fb , here is what I did :

My bridge header :

```
 #import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
 #import <FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit.h>
 #import <Parse/Parse.h>
 #import <Parse/PFObject+Subclass.h>
 #import <ParseUI/ParseUI.h>
 #import <ParseFacebookUtilsV4/PFFacebookUtils.h>
 #import <Bolts/Bolts.h>
```

My build phases screenshot  [image: screenshot]

In AppDelegate.swift :

```
    func application(application: UIApplication,
    openURL url: NSURL,
    sourceApplication: String?,
    annotation: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
        return       FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application,
            openURL: url,
            sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
            annotation: annotation)
}



    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    Parse.enableLocalDatastore()

    // Initialize Parse.
    Parse.setApplicationId("",
        clientKey: "") 
    return true
}
```

In my LoginViewController where I have IBoulet for login button

```
    var permissions = [ "public_profile", "email", "user_friends" ]

    @IBAction func facebookLogin(sender: AnyObject) {
    PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions(permissions,  block: {  (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if let user = user {
            if user.isNew {
                println("User signed up and logged in through Facebook!")

            } else {
                println("User logged in through Facebook!")

            }
        } else {
            println("Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.")
        }
    })
}
```

Let me know if you still have issues

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have figured out what is wrong, I had to remove the 'ParseFacebookUtils.framework' from the Build Phase